# Finding maximal region in $\Bbb R^2$ where the function satisfies heat equation

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I need to find the maximal region in $\Bbb R^2$ where the function $$u(x, t)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} e^{\frac{-x^2}{4 t}}, & t>0 \quad x \in \mathbb{R}, \\ 0, & t \leq 0, \quad x \in \mathbb{R},\end{array}\right.$$ is a solution of the heat equation.

It is clear that $u$ satisfies the heat equation $u_t=u_{xx},$ on both the half planes described by $t>0$ and $t<0$. Of course, we have to remove the origin as the limit $\lim_{t \to 0^+} u(0,t) \neq 0=\lim_{t \to 0^-} u(0,t)$ which violates the necessary continuity.

But what about the nature of $u$ at non-original points of $x$-axis?

Can I say, the continuity of $u(x,t)$ at non-zero points of $x$-axis should necessitates heat equation throughout $\Bbb R^2-\{(0,0)\}$? If so, how can I show the continuity?

Further, I've found that $u_{xx}(x,0)=0$, for any $x \in \Bbb R$ just through the definition of second derivative, and thereby $u_{xx}(x^*,0)=0$ for any non zero $x^*$. Now, I need to show $u_t(x^*,0)=0$ to conclude that $u$ is a solution for heat equation throughout $\Bbb R^2-\{(0,0)\}$. But I stuck at the limit $$\lim\limits_{k \to 0^-}\frac{u(x^*,k)-u(x^*,0)}{k}=\lim\limits_{k \to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt k}e^{-\frac{(x^*)^2}{4k}}}{k}=\lim\limits_{k \to 0}\frac{e^{-\frac{(x^*)^2}{4k}}}{k^{3/2}},$$I am sure the limit is $0$, but I couldn't establish it. Any help from you would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, so here $k\to 0$ while $k>0$. Otherwise the thing is identically zero. But when $k>0$ the numerator decays to $0$ exponentially, while the denominator is a power. The limit is zero.

Comment: Ya correct, but how to? L'Hôpital's rule is not working I think, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is actually much easier than you think. You did 99% of the job and stalled on the last trivial step. Consider
$$
\lim_{k\to 0^+} \frac{ 
e^{-\frac{x^2}{4k}} }{k^{3/2}},
$$
where $x\ne 0$. This limit is zero. Why? Well, I would say it is *manifestly true*, but if you want further evidence just put $h=x^2/(4k)$, so now $h\to \infty$. The limit becomes
$$
(4/x^2)^{3/2}\lim_{h\to \infty} \frac{h^{3/2}}{e^h} .$$
The multiplicative constant $(4/x^2)^{3/2}$ is irrelevant. You can easily prove that the limit is $0$ with your favorite tool; l'Hôpital rule, for example, works.